# "in" operator on select statement Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform an "in" on several rows :

```
case when  (select distinct A from b ) in  ('test,'y') then 2
```

I'm getting an error : "Subquery returned more than one row". 
Is there a way to make it works ?

EDIT :

This solution worked for me :

```
case when  exists (select  distinct a  from b
                        where a in  ('test','y')) then 2
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You really don't need to use a `DISTINCT` or even `a` in the subquery `SELECT`..
You should get in the habit of `SELECT 1` when using `EXISTS`. See my 1st answer.

Comment: Yup my bad, I just re-tested a bunch of stuff and forgot about your solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep it conceptually similar:

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a IN ('test', 'y')) THEN 2
```

If you need both `IN` values to be present in `b`'s `a` column:

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a) FROM b WHERE a IN ('test','y'))=2 THEN 2
```

Or if you simply want to return the number of distinct values in the `IN` condition then you don't need the `CASE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a) FROM b WHERE a IN ('test','y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from b
where a in ('x','y')
```